# In OpenCV, can you display the x, y and rgb values?

Tags: python, opencv

While following OpenCV tutorials, I noticed others have a display showing x and y coordinates like the screenshot below. Is this toolbar a feature of OpenCV? Is there a good way to implement a similar tooling that shows the current x, y and RGB of what has the mouse over?

[image: OpenCV toolbar]

Below is my current code snippet

```
import time

import cv2

def rescale_frame(frame, percent=75):
    width = int(frame.shape[2] * percent/ 100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120)

vid.read()
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    # capture the video frame by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    # display the resulting frame
    frame75 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=75)
    cv2.imshow('frame75', frame75)
    # cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [OpenCV's mouse callback](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html).

Here I've added the callback to print the BGR value of the pixel clicked on along with its coordinates into the named window `frame75`

The callback is initallized with,

```
cv2.namedWindow('frame75')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame75',mouse_pos_BGR)
```

And the callback function is,

```
def mouse_pos_BGR(event, x, y, flags, param):
    
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: # Left mouse click
        
        B = frame[y,x,0]
        G = frame[y,x,1]
        R = frame[y,x,2]
       
        print("Blue: ", B)
        print("Green: ", G)
        print("Red: ", R)        

        print("Coords x: ", x," y: ", y)
```

Full code listing,

```
import cv2
import time

def rescale_frame(frame, percent=75):
    
    width  = int(frame.shape[2] * percent/ 100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
    dim    = (width, height)
    
    return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)


def mouse_pos_BGR(event, x, y, flags, param):
    
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: # Left mouse click
        
        B = frame[y,x,0]
        G = frame[y,x,1]
        R = frame[y,x,2]
       
        print("Blue: ", B)
        print("Green: ", G)
        print("Red: ", R)        

        print("Coords x: ", x," y: ", y)


cv2.namedWindow('frame75')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame75',mouse_pos_BGR)


vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120)

vid.read()
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    # capture the video frame by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    # display the resulting frame
    frame75 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=75)
    cv2.imshow('frame75', frame75)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```